# I want to add a button with a image using tkinter, but my img is too big. How can I resize it, but display it as a png?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, image-resizing, ttkwidgets

I'm learning python and tkinter from scratch, by my own. I have this button:

```
info = tk.PhotoImage(file= "./assets/info.png")
boton_info = ttk.Button(f2, width=30, image= info)
boton_info.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky="nwe", padx=15)
```

I want to display a little info button. The img is 512x512 and it displays too big.
How can I resize the img and display it inside the Button??

I've tried this alternative to resize the img:

```
info_g = Image.open("./assets/info.png")
info = info_g.resize((30,30), Image.LANCZOS)
boton_info = ttk.Button(f2, width=30, image=info)
```

But I get this error
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPF0W.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `image` option of `tk.Button` expect `tk.PhotoImage` compatible image like the first example.

However, in the second example, you used an instance of `Image` (from `Pillow` module) which is not compatible to `tk.PhotoImage`.  You need to create the compatible image using `ImageTk.PhotoImage` class from `Pillow` module:

```py
info_g = Image.open("./assets/info.png")
info = info_g.resize((30,30), Image.LANCZOS)
tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(info) # create PhotoImage compatible image
boton_info = ttk.Button(f2, width=30, image=tkimg)
```